# Java: JSlider and taking its value by JTextArea

Tags: java

i need help with my code. I wanted to take value of slider by taking it from TextArea that show value of current position of slider but it takes starting value of it. 
This is my code:

```
JSlider ThicknessSlider = new JSlider(0,100,50);
JTextArea text4 = new JTextArea("0");
ThicknessSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSlider source=(JSlider)e.getSource();
        int value1 = (int)source.getValue();
        text4.setText(Integer.toString(value1));

        //String thickness1 = text4.getText();
    }});
String thickness1 = text4.getText();
this.thickness = Float.parseFloat(thickness1);
```

Comment: You're calling `text4.getText()` right after you create the slider. If you want to call it after the slider's state is changed, you need to move that code into the listener, to the spot where you have it commented out.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder thanks for fast response. Yeah i commented it because when i do it there is a problem with this line this.thickness = Float.parseFloat(thickness1);

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `setText` and the next line into the ChangeListener.

The problem is that `this` refers to the ChangeListener in that context. You can add a setter `setThickness` to your class and call that, or you can use `YourClassName.this.thickness` to specify which `this` you mean.

Comment: that helped . Thank you very much :)